# Display data in a label in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a question. How to display data from database in label in WinForm?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Shop\Shop\shop.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection myDbconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myDbconnection.Open();
    sqlQRY = "Select prix from fleurs where nom='"+flori.SelectedValue+"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQRY, myDbconnection);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        label6.Text = 'prix'.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

I need to show "prix" in `label6.Text`.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: It is displaying exactly what you told it to.

Comment: He means he wants the value of the 'prix' column in the database. @Menfis ExecuteScalar is the right method to use if you only have one value from one row - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are not getting any other error. this should be enough

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   label6.Text = "prix";

}
```

if you want to read it from database and prix is the name of column in your database then you can read it like this

```
label6.Text = reader["prix"].ToString();
```

Comment: @MenfisMenfis what is the name of column in your databasE?

Answer (score 0):

You did a *syntax error* in your code: *apostrophes* ' are used for `characters`, not strings, e.g.

```
Char myChar = 'a';
```

If you want just to print out "prix", you should use *quotations* ", e.g.

```
if (reader.HasRows) 
{ 
    label6.Text = "prix"; // not label6.Text = 'prix'.ToString();
    ...
```

Method `ToString()` is *excessive* in your case: `"prix"` is a *string* already.

If you want to *read database field* with the name `"prix"` you should put it

```
if (reader.HasRows) 
{
    label6.Text = reader["prix"].toString(); // <- "prix" can't be null 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.    `label6.Text = reader["prix"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a lot of assumptions here.

One of which, is there is ONE row returned (since you have ONE label)

You should use `ExecuteScalar`

It is not recommended to use DataReader and Command.ExecuteReader to get just on value from the database

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Shop\Shop\shop.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection myDbconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myDbconnection.Open();
        sqlQRY = "Select prix from fleurs where nom='"+flori.SelectedValue+"'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQRY, myDbconnection);

        var value = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            label6.Text = value;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because your query is not returning any data

Answer (score -2):

We can use this statement

```
label6.Text = "prix";
```